# Exporting labels in a pdf

Tags: java, pdf-generation, itext, apache-poi

I am managing a java web application and I want to make a pdf export that contains some labels with a logo on them and some data like “id”.
What is the best way to do that.
I am thinking something like iText (I am not only intresting in html to pdf converter) but I am not sure if I can include images and borders in my tickets.
Every proposal is welcome.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Repeating a template in Apache POI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585408/repeating-a-template-in-apache-poi)

Comment: You should update your existing question with new details, rather than asking a new one

Comment: Sorry I am not sure that I can do it with apache poi so I posted it for other suggestion. Can I delete a question?

Comment: iText can use PDF templates, POI can use .dot templates. Choose based on that.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is create from scratch PDF files that contain images and text, then yes, iText can do that (and much much more). Edit your question with further details about your requirements if a more detailed answer.